# Typescript Error: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript, http, get, ionic3

I have the following code to get coordinates from a JSON file and creating markers on the map:

```
getMarkers() {
 this.http.get('src/assets/data/markers.json')
 .map((res) => res.json())
 .subscribe(data => {
  this.addMarkersToMap(data);
 });
}


addMarkersToMap(markers) {
 for(let marker of markers) {
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
  var dogwalkMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title:marker.title});
   dogwalkMarker.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

My JSON file:

```
   [
  {
   "latitude": 12.8418306,
   "longitude": 77.6468554,
   "name": "Area1"
   },
 {
  "latitude": 12.8424916,
  "longitude": 77.6518233,
  "name": "Area2"
  },
 {
  "latitude": 12.8407116,
  "longitude": 77.6486245,
  "name": "Area3"
  }
]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[ts] Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

I've imported 'rxjs/add/operator/map'.

I looked at other posts regarding this problem but I couldn't solve this issue.

Comment: which line is causing the error? can you post the full log?

Comment: getMarkers() {
 this.http.get('src/assets/data/markers.json')
 .map((res) => res.json())

Comment: This line is giving the error.